# Is there a tool for building races using point system?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, races, tool-recommendation

I have a party. All players want exotic races. They know what they want and power level seems to be in line with or little above races found in SRD. We talked, and I agreed these races would exist in my world and are feasible in my campaign.  It's campaign designed for 4-5 players and it seems I'll have only 3, so I honestly don't mind giving them some extra kick at the beginning.

That said, I want their characters to have similar power level. No one should outshine anyone there, except in his area of expertise. So I need to tweak races (probably design one, too). With [race creation rules and their point system](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/other-rules/creating-new-races) it's trial and error process - if I would just snap features that fits the fluff we sketched, power level would vary wildly.  And if I would just stop adding features at preselected point value, "look and feel" of these races would perish.

It would be easier if I could just click this, remove that and see race mechanics and it's RP, instead of manual calculations.  Faster, less chance for simple calculation errors, you know all the things people invented computers for. We all have better things to do than waste our time for something that can be done faster on computer, best proof is that we are here instead of sending each other some paper letters. Anyway, no other question in [tool-recommendation](/questions/tagged/tool-recommendation) seems to even bother with justifying why to use software tools.

**I need a tool to test various combinations to get the same point value (or at least similar), and not lose the flavor of it.**

I would prefer online or Windows solutions, but Android might work, too. I'll gladly read about tools for other platforms, but I will not be able to accept such answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you make new playable races?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/53944/how-do-you-make-new-playable-races)

Comment: @ObliviousSage I know how to make races. I'm looking for software to speed it up.

Comment: I've closed is as a "shopping" question. If you want to describe what problem the existing system causes you with enough detail that people can help solve the problem, not just supply the answer you're hoping for, add more information about the exact problem you have with the manual method. "Too slow" doesn't describe the problem, just its symptom—tell us how you're using it and why it's slow, and maybe why just doing it slow isn't acceptable. Then let answerers help the core problem how they think best, instead of assuming software is the answer.

Comment: This is still a shopping question and will remain closed until it's not. “no other question in tools seems to even bother with justifying why to use software tools” because that's the wrong tag to use (use [tools] for questions about how to use a specific tool; use [tool-recommendation] to ask for a tool), and because we recently made recommendation questions off-topic. To fix this, step back from your desired solution (a tool) and ask about the problem. Maybe make the question about “How do I speed up using the Creating New Races rules?” People can answer that with tools, or other things.

Comment: [I have written some guidance on how to turn a recommendation question into a non-recommendation question.](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5787/i-want-to-ask-for-recommendations-but-thats-off-topic-is-there-any-way-to-ask) You might find it useful for getting this reopened.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie And how [this](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/68277/10642) isn't a shopping question? Or [this](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/67317/10642)? Or [this](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/65745/10642)? There is even less explanation than here.

Comment: @Mołot The rule changed only last month. Bringing old questions to moderator attention will only get them closed as off-topic, not persuade moderators to reopen this without changes.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie It's been more than a month since I asked here, must have missed it. So basically all tool recommendations are offtopic here now? Sad thing. Bye for now.

Comment: @Mołot That is the case. The link I just provided might be helpful to read though, as it provides two ways to get the question answered.